# php global associative array null when included from ajax

Tags: php, ajax, null, associative-array

i have a problem that i cannot understand.

i have a file declaring some arrays and some function : passerelles/zoho_API_START.php

you can see the array declaration at the beginning of the file :

```
$arrayProfils = array(
    "INVESTISSEMENT" => "Achat invest",
    "RESIDENCE PRINCIPALE" => "Achat RP"
);
```

then the function

```
function CRM_lead_upsert ($lead, $fichierlog) {

    $logZoho = fopen($fichierlog, "a+");

    global $arrayType;
    global $arrayProfils;
    global $arraySourceLibelles;

    //fwrite($logZoho, "debut print 2 tableau arraySourceLibelles\r\n");
    //fwrite($logZoho, var_export($arraySourceLibelles, true));
    //fwrite($logZoho, "fin print 2 tableau arraySourceLibelles\r\n");

    try{    
        [...]
        $indexTMP = $lead['typeprojet'];
        $profil = $arrayProfils[$indexTMP];
        fwrite($logZoho, "Lead Upsert profil=indexTMP=".$indexTMP."\r\n");
        fwrite($logZoho, "Lead Upsert profil=arrayProfils[indexTMP]=".$profil."\r\n");
        fwrite($logZoho, var_export($arrayProfils, true)."\r\n");       
        $record->setFieldValue("Lead_profile", $profil);
        [...]
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        fwrite($logZoho, date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." *** Exception insertion lead line 543 zoho api ***\r\n");
        fwrite($logZoho, date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." ".$e." \r\n");
    }

    fclose($logZoho);
}
```

the problem is :
when i'm calling this into a simple php file (zoho_API_OK_Leads_insert.php) , everything is ok (my var_export($arrayProfils, true) in the log file display the correct values) :

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);

//include("zoho_API_START.php");
include("passerelles/zoho_API_START.php");

if (true) {
    $lead['idProgramme'] = 899;
    //$idLot = "21669"; 
    //$lead['idAnnonce'] = 21670;
    $lead['typeprojet']="INVESTISSEMENT";
    $lead['nom']="Toto";
    $lead['prenom']="";
    $lead['telephone']="0605060506";
    $lead['email']="test@toto.fr";
    $lead['type'] = 1;
    $lead['cpdemande']="69200";
    $lead['nbpieces'] = 3;
    $lead['budgetmax'] = 250000;
    $lead['infosComplementaires']="infos.";
    $lead['adresse'] = "";
    $lead['cpresidence'] ="";
    $lead['ville'] ="Lyon";
    $lead['impots']="";
    $lead['utm_source']="";
    $lead['utm_campaign']="";
    $lead['Lead_Status'] = "Non attribué";
    CRM_lead_upsert ($lead, "admin/00_logZohoAPI.txt");
}


echo "c'est terminé<br>";


?>
```

but when i'm calling the same code (exactly the same, from within the same directory) within an ajax file, my var_export($arrayProfils, true) is written in the log file as null.
See code from the ajax file (ajax_formPOST.php) :

```
include("passerelles/zoho_API_START.php");
/************************
// POUR LE CRM DEBUT
************************/
CRM_lead_upsert ($data, "admin/00_logZohoAPI.txt"); 
/************************
// POUR LE CRM FIN
************************/
```

The only difference is that i call ajax_formPOST.php via a xhr request with post method. When i do that my associative array is null.
I have other arrays which are non associative (integer as key) that are working without any problem even via ajax. I cannot figure out what the problem is.

please note that i don't want a patch (an adhesive bandage like "change your array and make the same with integer keys") but i want to understand what's happening here.
If somebody has a clue...

Thanks for your time and have a good day.

---

### Found something !!

if i declare my arrays like that :

```
$arrayProfils = array(
    "INVESTISSEMENT" => "Achat invest",
    "RESIDENCE PRINCIPALE" => "Achat RP"
);
$GLOBALS['arrayProfils'] = $arrayProfils;
```

then in my function and via an ajax call, $arrayProfils contains values and isn't anymore NULL.

There is a subtility that i still cannot understand... (and i'm still listening to someone that can explain me...)

Comment: Do you see anything on console?

Comment: yes, my logfile is written so my script is correctly called via ajax and everything else works fine 
i can see the call in the console and see the response

Comment: So where exactly is `$data` coming from in the script that you trigger via AJAX …?

Comment: from my $_POST variable. i need to clarify that my $lead['typeprojet'] display the correct value in both case.